# Einstein bot unable to open in firefox incognito mode

Tags: servicecloud, einstein-chatbot, chatbot

I am trying to open einstein chatbot in firefox browser in incognito mode. In Incognito mode it is not opening chatbot in normal mode it is opening

Comment: Can you try by changing cookie settings in incognito mode to allow 3rd party cookies nd see if that works?

Comment: We have disabled Enhanced tracking protection on incognito browser after that chatbot started working